# Image doesn't resize in flex-box stretch

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div that has 3 elements: 2 buttons and an image.  I want the height of the image to adjust to the buttons. I thought using Flexbox's align-items property and setting it to "stretch" would work perfectly for this.  My thought process was that by setting an absolute height for the buttons and not setting a height for the image, the image would automatically stretch to the height of the buttons.

I first attempted this with 2 buttons and a div and it worked perfectly! However, when I use an image instead, the image refused to resize.  Below is a very minimal example of my code.

CSS:

```
div {
    background-color: #000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

button {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

img {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML (excluding obvious tags such as HTML, body, etc.):

```
<div>
    <button>This is the first button</button>
    <button>This is the secod button</button>
    <img src="./desktop-screenshot.png"/>
</div>
```

This is a screenshot of when minimally reproduced example is opened in a browser.
[open screenshot of index.html in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TettG.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try This code it will work

```css
div {
    background-color: #000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    height:100px;
}

button {
    flex:0 0 auto;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

img {
    flex:0 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button>This is the first button</button>
    <button>This is the secod button</button>
    <img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/3MbF54EhWUhsXunc5Keueb/60774fbbff86e6bf6776f1e17a8016b4/04-nature_721703848.jpg?fit=fill&w=480&h=270"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the display to `display: flex;` and added a width percentage like this :

```css
div {
    background-color: #000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

button {
    width: 250px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

img {
    display: flex;
    width:33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button>This is the first button</button>
    <button>This is the secod button</button>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TettG.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
    background-color: #000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

button {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

img {
    display: block;
  width:250px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button>This is the first button</button>
    <button>This is the secod button</button>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/R8BlhKf.png"/>
</div>
```